# Delete rows if found string or special character in a particular column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have my data as say `df`-

```
data = [['Gs01', 'safety'],[44325, 'eLearning_since_2001'],[889, 'air exhaust_open_chamber'],['Fireman\9801','internal_fireman']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['e code', 'training'])
df1


e code     training
Gs01         safety
44325        eLearning_since_2001
889          air exhaust_open_chamber
Fireman\9801 internal_fireman
```

In e code column, it is the employee code and there is some code which I want to delete the row for these codes only like - Gs01, Fireman9801 because it contains string and some characters which is not a genuine employee code, and deleted row must be stored in any other dataframe say `excluded_df` so my OP should be -
`df1`-

```
e code     training
44325        eLearning_since_2001
889          air exhaust_open_chamber
```

`excluded_df`-

```
e code     training
Gs01         safety
Fireman\9801 internal_fireman
```

Please help me to achieve the above result using python, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we say that you want to delete any row with a code having non numeric digits?

Comment: You can use, [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) setting ``errors='coerce'`` latter drop those rows with NaN values.

Comment: Exactly, something like: ```df1[pd.to_numeric(df1'e code'], errors='coerce').notnull()]```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes absolutely correct, the data consist of 3 lacs+ rows, so any row other than numeric digit, it should get deleted

Comment: @sophocles hey mate, happy to see u after a long time, I knew u coz in my brothers account I posted first question in SO and it was answered by you only :)

Comment: @sushanth thanks for the info, it really helpful and thanks to sophocles too.

Comment: Hi buddy, happy to see you again too. You are very welcome.

Comment: @sophocles by applying your code it only returns  me e code column, training column  was not there.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have shown the complete example as an answer below. Please have a look. It seems to be working as per your needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231450/discussion-between-sophocles-and-l-for-learning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the data you posted:

```
>>> df1.to_dict()

{'e code': {0: 'Gs01', 1: 44325, 2: 889, 3: 'Fireman\\9801'},
 'training': {0: 'safety',
  1: 'eLearning_since_2001',
  2: 'air exhaust_open_chamber',
  3: 'internal_fireman'}}

>>> df1

         e code                  training
0          Gs01                    safety
1         44325      eLearning_since_2001
2           889  air exhaust_open_chamber
3  Fireman\9801          internal_fireman
```

Applying this code:

```
new = df1[pd.to_numeric(df1['e code'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
```

Yields back:

```
  e code                  training
1  44325      eLearning_since_2001
2    889  air exhaust_open_chamber
```